# Repeat the same youtube id url in a playlist?

Tags: javascript, function, youtube, constants, var

Is it possible to put in an array of youtube video IDs (video1, video2, video3, etc) a promo video (for example: VIDEOX) repeated and interspersed with the other videos?
for example: video1, VIDEOX, video2, VIDEOX, video3, VIDEOX ..... Because I tried but it only shows me VIDEOX once and then it goes on with the others.

```
const videos = {
'RGpr3Y6Q-1M': 'picture1.png',
'y9R1TpNWGK8': 'promo.png',
'btxdcqLOGuc': 'picture2.png',
'y9R1TpNWGK8': 'promo.png',
'CIx0a1vcYPc': 'picture3.png',
'y9R1TpNWGK8': 'promo.png',
};
```

Comment: Maybe include some code (debugging details)? We can't magically guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: here you can see a demo about the problem http://jsfiddle.net/kq2mrxvb/

Comment: if you click on the "next" button after the first video you will see the promotional video (y9R1TpNWGK8), but only once, then it will no longer show despite being in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there is the `videos` object:

```js
const videos = {
'RGpr3Y6Q-1M': 'http://nothingbutgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/automata_16x9.png',
'y9R1TpNWGK8': 'https://blog.giallozafferano.it/viaggiandomangiando/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1200px-Break.com_Logo_2017.svg_.png',
'btxdcqLOGuc': 'https://live.staticflickr.com/2400/2078946248_d063d5a563_b.jpg',
'y9R1TpNWGK8': 'https://blog.giallozafferano.it/viaggiandomangiando/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1200px-Break.com_Logo_2017.svg_.png',
'CIx0a1vcYPc': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CIx0a1vcYPc/maxresdefault.jpg',
'y9R1TpNWGK8': 'https://blog.giallozafferano.it/viaggiandomangiando/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1200px-Break.com_Logo_2017.svg_.png',
};
```

The first part of each line is the property name. The first property name above is `RGpr3Y6Q-1M`. Each property name must be unique, but in this code we are reusing the same property name three times. That is the problem.

This problem means that all the subsequent lines starting with `y9R1TpNWGK8` are ignored, because we already used that property name.

A solution to this is to use an array instead of an object, because in an array we can have duplicate values.

Like so:

```js
const videos = [
[ 'RGpr3Y6Q-1M', 'http://nothingbutgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/automata_16x9.png' ],
[ 'y9R1TpNWGK8', 'https://blog.giallozafferano.it/viaggiandomangiando/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1200px-Break.com_Logo_2017.svg_.png' ],
[ 'btxdcqLOGuc', 'https://live.staticflickr.com/2400/2078946248_d063d5a563_b.jpg' ],
[ 'y9R1TpNWGK8', 'https://blog.giallozafferano.it/viaggiandomangiando/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1200px-Break.com_Logo_2017.svg_.png' ],
[ 'CIx0a1vcYPc', 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CIx0a1vcYPc/maxresdefault.jpg' ],
[ 'y9R1TpNWGK8', 'https://blog.giallozafferano.it/viaggiandomangiando/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1200px-Break.com_Logo_2017.svg_.png' ],
];
```

We only need to make a couple of other minor changes elsewhere, so that it treats `videos` as an array instead of an object. I've done that here: http://jsfiddle.net/vLd34wnx/